# Dumping DataFrame to JSON records

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as:

```
   task_count  task   date
0  82586       foo     2015-10-31
1  57417       foo     2016-08-31
2  47800       bar     2016-12-31
3  62331       foo     2016-02-29
4  45852       bar     2017-07-31
```

I want to generate an output as:

```
[
  {
    "task": "foo",
    "task_count": [82586,57417,62331],
    "date": ["2015-10-31","2016-08-31","2016-02-29"]
  },
  {
    "task": "bar",
    "task_count": [47800,45852],
    "date": ["2016-12-31","2017-07-31"]
  }
]
```

So far this is what i've done but i'm not able to perform groupby on multiple columns.

```
result = df.groupby('task')['task_count'].apply(list).reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
print(json.dumps(json.loads(result),indent=2)
```

What should be my approach to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `agg` + `to_dict` -

```
df.groupby('task', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict('r')
[
    {
        "date": [
            "2016-12-31",
            "2017-07-31"
        ],
        "task_count": [
            47800,
            45852
        ],
        "task": "bar"
    },
    {
        "date": [
            "2015-10-31",
            "2016-08-31",
            "2016-02-29"
        ],
        "task_count": [
            82586,
            57417,
            62331
        ],
        "task": "foo"
    }
]
```

---

If you want to generate JSON and dump the result to a file, use `to_json` instead of `to_dict` -

```
df.groupby('task', as_index=False)\
  .agg(lambda x: x.tolist())\
  .to_json('file.json', orient='records')
```

Which creates a `file.json` containing -

```
[{"task":"bar","task_count":[47800,45852],"date":["2016-12-31","2017-07-31"]},{"task":"foo","task_count":[82586,57417,62331],"date":["2015-10-31","2016-08-31","2016-02-29"]}]'
```

Comment: this seems to work but somehow my date field's values have changed to some random integers. Also as i'm new to python, could you please explain what does ' r ' parameter do in to_dict() ?

Comment: @GabbarSingh `r` is an alias for "records" which means that a list of records should be returned. Also, I don't really know why `to_dict` should result in random numbers replacing your data.

Comment: @COLDSPEED that's because the `date` column in dataframe `df` wasn't really a string and when inserted into the `df` was of 'date' data type in the database. any work around that you could suggest for this?

Comment: @GabbarSingh Convert to string? `df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)`

Comment: Very neat solution - like it very much!